# VB6 TextStream in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

What is alternative in c# for VB6 TextStream?

Below Code-in VB6

```
ByRef strVarianceRpt As TextStream
```

**How to write this in C#? OR any other alternative in C#?**

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent in C# would probably be a `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` dependent upon whether you are reading or writing to a file.

A `StreamReader`:

> Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a
>   particular encoding.

Conversely, a `StreamWriter`:

> Implements a TextWriter for writing characters to a stream in a
>   particular encoding.

Some examples of using them (taken from the MS Documentation) are:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

For the writer:

```
DirectoryInfo[] cDirs = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").GetDirectories();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CDriveDirs.txt"))
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in cDirs)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);
    }
}
```

Information can be found about StreamReader from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader).  The equivalent form StreamWriter are in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter).

Comment: Plus One. Also OP could look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object) for the `TextStream` object referred to in the question, which is part of the FileSystemObject library i.e. not technically part of VB6.

Comment: As @MarkJ points out it is a COM object and C# can use COM objects. If porting code perhaps using the COM object will be easier as there are a few slight differences (so lots of small fiddly changes required), between a .NET and this FSO COM stream. (There are other types of streams available in .NET and COM such as ADODB and these port easy).